# Can't Install any Software with apt: " 'install-info' contains empty filename"

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I've searched but I can't find anything specific to my case. I'm running Kali 2021.4 and I'm having trouble using `apt` to do anything. I'm told I should run `apt --fix-broken install` and I do and I get:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3.9 libpython3.9-dev libpython3.9-minimal libpython3.9-stdlib python3.9 python3.9-dev python3.9-minimal
Suggested packages:
  python3.9-venv python3.9-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.9 libpython3.9-dev libpython3.9-minimal libpython3.9-stdlib python3.9 python3.9-dev python3.9-minimal
7 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2199 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 73.7 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'install-info' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2) "
```

I've tried a lot of things, and frankly there's no telling what I've done to my system at this point. Backing up files now, but any help that could save me from a reinstall would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can be reproduced by adding an empty line in a package's file list about to be upgraded (to-be-upgraded is maybe not a prerequisite to trigger it). So some previously made action damaged the content of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.list` which you should search for anomaly.

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean up `/var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.list`, and then, to be safe, re-install `install-info`:

```
sudo sed -i '/^$/d' /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.list
sudo apt reinstall install-info
```

Once that’s done, other `apt` operations should work properly.